# Convert NSString to NSDate that has +00:00 at the end of it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Can someone please tell me how I can convert this string:

```
2011-07-25T10:12:59-05:00
```

to an NSDate object? I have converted GMT date strings before with an NSDateFormat that looked like @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS", but I have no idea how to configure it for this string.

Also, what do I set my [NSDateFormatter timeZone] to be?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Whether that colon in the timezone must come? Because we can convert it easily it is in the format `2011-07-25T10:12:59-0500`

Comment: The given time is about to YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD this format , i got this from http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime , i dnt know the answer but i think this will help you in solving it thank you

Answer (score 0):

## Problem Solved !

You can convert your string to NSDate this way,

```
NSString *dateString = @"2011-07-25T10:12:59-05:00";
NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```